# Inject variable into php include

Tags: php, include, scope, inject

I've seen a number of questions here about using variables from an include that look like this:

test.inc.php:

```
<?php
$variable = "value";
?>
```

file.php:

```
<?php
$variable = "something";
include "test.inc.php";
echo $variable; // Should be "value"
```

Now I'm trying to do it in reverse, and am unsuccessful.  This is what it looks like:

template.html.php:

```
<html><body>Here is the value from the inherited scope: <?= $variable ?></body></html>
```

file.php:

```
<?php
$variable = "it's a'me, a'mario!";
include "template.html.php";
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
<html><body>Here is the value from the inherited scope: it's a'me, a'mario!</body></html>
```

But instead, it is:

```
<html><body>Here is the value from the inherited scope: </body></html>
```

Is there any sane way to inject the $variable into the include file?  I'm writing a pseudo-templating engine that is based on code previously written by another person, and I am forced to go down this route.

I've thought about using eval, but I need to capture all of the output, and I'm not sure I can do that using eval based on how the included file actually looks.

So how would I go about injecting variables into an include file?

Comment: What you're doing should work. Some confusion in filenames though - your `template.html.php` is not what you're including - you included `include_me.php`.  File includes will inherit function scope, but if you defined `$variable` in the same scope as the `include`, it should be available there.

Comment: You have `include "include_me.php";` shouldn't that be `include "template.html.php";`? Plus, is short open tags ON? If not, change `<?=` to `<?php echo`. I got back `Here is the value from the inherited scope: it's a'me, a'mario!` in doing so.

Comment: Yes, if you have PHP < 5.4 and short_open_tag isn't enabled, `<?=` won't be parsed. You would see it if you view the page source, as HTML would just hide it from you.  But if you have 5.4+ or short_open_tag enabled, what you have will work (given the right filenames)

Comment: From seeing your edit, it seems like this could be a short tags issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the include bug, but that was just from me copy/pasting from two different test php files I've written, so we can rule that out.

Comment: Short tags have been enabled on the server

Comment: can you show us the full code in `template.html.php`, I highly suspect that there is another `$variable` overrides the value of it.

Comment: Ah, sorted it out.  The previous developer had two definitions of the function that included the template, and both had the same data but with different variable names, and the template assumed the wrong names.  I removed the duplicate function and everything functions as expected now.